# Users without write access can still star messages

Tags: bug, chat

In a chat room that's in gallery (i.e., users need to receive permission to send messages), users with no special permissions can still star messages (something that's most definitely 'writing' to the room).

Example: The two stars [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54537/sandbox) were me, despite not even requesting permission.

Comment: This can be quite annoying when muted users get "revenge" by spamming stars on us.

Comment: This is currently intentional; you only need read access to star messages. But I guess a case could be made otherwise, so maybe you can turn this into a feature request, explaining why you think it should be changed (and @RUJordan examples of what you say there might be helpful in that regard).